# Timeout on deploying firebase files

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a simple static HTML and CSS website, a total of 19 files, when I use firebase deploy for the first time it uploads all files except 3 (which I don't know what are they), and then I use firebase deploy again and I get this error with a timeout

> Error: Task
> 746db75fe2e30f7db8e598da508ea0151037c4fa9ee122daec252dc18fbb8662
> failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: Timeout
> reached making request to
> https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/xxxx/versions/0e578bbd3fa0f905/files/746db75fe2e30f7db8e598da508ea0151037c4fa9ee122daec252dc18fbb8662

My version of firebase is **10.0.1** 
My Node version is **17.3.0**

Comment: Are you uploading any json file? Are you uploading any big files?

Comment: @Gourav B nope, my folder is almost only 3 MB, and it's just a simple static html page with some css and image files

Comment: Can you share firebase-debug.log file, which should be in project's root. Also the output of "firebase deploy --only hosting" command.

Comment: @Gourav B  here's the log file https://pastebin.com/KbBkVeeE
and the output of the command is `Error: Task 374ca434ad51363e53442990832e77c2515633b4e57d4407f2ddf4ce2899c437 failed: retries exhausted after 6 attempts, with error: Timeout reached making request to https://upload-firebasehosting.googleapis.com/upload/sites/jobs-co-suu/versions/57b5b81d80f580d6/files/374ca434ad51363e53442990832e77c2515633b4e57d4407f2ddf4ce2899c437`

Comment: Look at this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2126) which has some workaround ideas worth trying. Also, seems the issue is with jpg files.

Answer (score 3):

I had a (not quite the same but) similar error while trying to deploy firebase functions and hosting in WSL2. I tried to install different firebase-tools versions, and logout then login again, nothing works.

It turns out that the [WSL2 DNS issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5256) caused this problem.

So if you're deploying firebase behind WSL2 try this ([credit](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-522201021)):

```
1. Create a file: /etc/wsl.conf.
2. Put the following lines in the file
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
3. In a cmd window, run wsl --shutdown
4. Restart WSL2
5. Create a file: /etc/resolv.conf. If it exists, replace existing one with this new file.
6. Put the following lines in the file
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If `/etc/resolv.conf` is deleted every you restart WSL2, and you're on Windows 11, add these lines to the end of the above `/etc/wsl.conf` file.

```
[boot]
command = "printf 'nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 4.4.4.4' > /etc/resolv.conf"
```

Comment: THANK YOU! THIS SHOULD BE SOMEWARE IN THE FIREBASE DOCS!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps which might help in troubleshooting the issue :

- Delete  `node modules` and reinstall them again.
- Delete `firebase files`
  (.firebase, firebase.json)
- Update Firebase CLI via `"npm i -g firebase-tools"`
- Log in to your account via `"firebase login"`
- Initialize the project via `"firebase init hosting"`
- And lastly deploy
  it via `"firebase deploy --only hosting"`

You can also refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) for further details on Firebase hosting.

Comment: My folder is only 2.84 MB, it only has .html and .css and .jpg and .png files
I tried updating firebase tools and removing node modules
I tried to deploy everything again but it still gets stuck at 3 files,

Comment: however when I try to update the firebase tools

I get this deprecated warning for some libraries

https://pastebin.com/PWfYt6nK

Comment: try upgrading the firebase version and see..if problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your favicon.png is in the correct formart https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines